# How to split data loaded to a dropdown dynamically from database using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a dropdown in which the options are populated dynamically from the database using jquery. The code is:

```
    $('.Input').html("");
    for(i=0, len=data.length; i<len; i++){
    $('.Input').append('<option>' + data[i].abc  + '</option');
                        }
```

the HTML is:

```
<select class="Input"></select>
```

This works perfectly when the data itself is separated by newline. Im facing an issue when the value is the database is stored as  abc = [x,y,z]. The dropdown shows it as x,y,z instead of having them in newline.

I tried using

```
var listItems = "<option value=''> </option>";
$.each(data[0].abc, function(index, title) {
listItems+= "<option value='" + title+ "'>" + title+ "</option>";});
$("#selectItems").html(listItems);
```

and my corresponding HTML as:

```
<select id="selectItems"></select>
```

but in this case, if it is a single option in the database, the option is split by its letters. for example APPLE would come as A P P L E with each letter in a new line.

Any suggestions on what I can do?

Comment: What does your data exactly look like returned from the server? Is it json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript can work with arrauy elements in the same way as with chars in a string.
You should check the kind of data you have.

I have not clear with your example where is the array you want to transform (data, or data[0].abc, or data is an array with an object and you want the element abc in each,...)

Maybe this example can give you an idea:

```
var listItems = "<option value=''> </option>";

if( typeof data === 'string' ) {
   listItems+= "<option value='" + data+ "'>" + data+ "</option>";
} else {
   $.each(data, function(element) {
      listItems+= "<option value='" + element.abc+ "'>" + element.abc+ "</option>";
   });
}
$("#selectItems").html(listItems);
```